# How to append a list withoud adding the quote

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have this code:

```
def add_peer_function():
    all_devices=[]
    all_devices.append("cisco,linux")
    print(all_devices)

add_peer_function()
```

Which results in :

```
['cisco,linux']
```

My question is how can append the list without qota. So a result like this:

```
[cisco,router]
```

Comment: Strings are *displayed* in single or double quotes, this just isn't what you want

Comment: As the things you're aiming to append are strings, it will not be possible to omit the quotes. However, you're currently appending one string, containing two words that are separated by a comma. To append two individual strings, use two `append()` calls or use `all_devices += ["cisco", "linux"]`.

Comment: @applesoup or a single `.extend` call which is probably more efficient

Comment: @DeepSpace: Sure, that also works. However, in my opinion, the `+=` operator could be interpreted as being more *pythonic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I know two possible ways, but the first one is faster:

**1**:

```
def add_peer_function():
    all_devices=[item for item in "cisco,linux".split(',')] # or `all_devices = ["cisco", "linux"]`
    print(', '.join(all_devices)) # A prettier way to print list Thanks to Philo

add_peer_function()
```

**2**:

```
def add_peer_function():
    all_devices=[] 
    for item in "cisco,linux".split(','): # or `all_devices = ["cisco", "linux"]`
        all_devices.append(item)

    print(', '.join(all_devices)) # A prettier way to print list Thanks to Philo

add_peer_function()
```

Python [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) documentation.

Python [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) documentation.

Python [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Python prints objects, by default, with its convention: strings are between quotes.

If you want to get another format, you can write your own formatter.

For lists of strings, a common pattern in Python is:

```
my_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print(', '.join(my_list))
```

Replace ', ' by another separator, eventually.

Finally, note that "cisco,linux" is just a string with a coma, which is different from a list of strings: ["cisco", "linux"].

Answer (score -1):

Of course, if you append the string `'cisco,linux'` to a list, you get `['cisco,linux']` which is the string representation of this list in Python.

What you what is to [split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) the string.

Try:

```
>>> 'cisco,linux'.split(',')
['cisco', 'linux']
```

Answer (score -1):

append accepts only one argument. so, `your_list.append(something)` will add something to `your_list`. you can however do sth like below.

`your_list += [el for el in "cisco,linux".split(",")]`